# Jruby 1.7.13 ignores debugger statement even with --debug flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rspec, jruby

I'm trying to start a debugger session to track down a bug in one of my Rails projects. So I stuck a debugger statement in the problem area and called my rake spec command.

For the debugger to work, I'm supposed to start jruby with the --debug flag. When I do this, a bunch of debugger information hits the console but I still get the same 'jruby needs --debug flag' and jruby ignores the debugger statement.

Here's the command:`jruby --debug -S rspec spec/models/relational_dataset_spec.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer while looking at related questions, but I've decided to ask and answer my own question because none of the other questions were relevant enough to warrant the answer below.

Moving the --debug statement helped a lot. Here's what I was trying before:

`jruby --debug -S rspec spec/models/relational_dataset_spec.rb`

this lead to a bunch of debug information to hit the console so I thought it was in the right place. However, the tracing warning was still showing up. When I moved the --debug statement here,

`jruby -S rspec --debug spec/models/relational_dataset_spec.rb`

the debug information disappeared, the tracing warning still showed up, but the debugger stopped in the right place. Perhaps the rspec is running another instance of jruby, which also needs it's own --debug flag? I hope someone can come and give a good answer to this.